# Attributes toolbar not working

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am an engineering student from Sweden. In the course I'm currently reading, we will use QGIS. In our compendium they refer to something called "Select Feature" in the Attribute Toolbar but I can't find this as my Attributes Toolbar only includes this (see image below). Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: You can find the Select toolbar in the image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTNWK.png

Comment: Aha, alright thank you so much for your quick answer guys, what a community! <3

Answer (score 0):

Select Features is in the selection toolbar which you already have visible:
[image]